# GetFiles returns incorrect number of files when filename contains a bracket

Tags: c#, getfiles

I need to copy files from one directory to another, however if the filename is already present in the target directory - I need to make it unique, all files need to be copied without overwriting.

I have the following code:

```
String filenameBody = fi.Name.Substring(0, fi.Name.Length - fi.Extension.Length);
String fileDup = String.Format("{0}*{1}", filenameBody, fi.Extension);

FileInfo[] fiNotFound = diNotFound.GetFiles(fileDup);

if (fiNotFound.Length > 0)
   newFilename = Path.Combine(diNotFound.ToString(), 
      String.Format("{0}_{1}{2}", filenameBody, fiNotFound.Length + 1,fi.Extension));
else 
    newFilename = Path.Combine(diNotFound.ToString(), fi.Name);

fi.MoveTo(newFilename);
Console.WriteLine(" Not Found");
```

The problem arises when the filename contains a bracket, e.g. (1).pdf GetFiles only returns one file back when I give it the pattern (1)*.pdf, but I happen to know there are at least two - so when the MoveTo is called it fails with file already exists - so how can I use GetFiles when the filename is in this pattern?

Comment: are you trying to remove extention in first line? you can do `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name));` instead of `fi.Name.Substring(0, fi.Name.Length - fi.Extension.Length);`

Comment: A work around would be `diNotFound.EnumerateFiles().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(filenameBody) && x.Extension == fi.Extension).ToArray()`

Comment: What are the names of the files you are trying to match?